# Confusing Analysis proof

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, surfaces

I have a question about a proof of the Beltrami-Enneper theorem:
In the following $\nu$ is the surface-normal and $e_1,e_2,e_3$ the Frenet 3-frame.

It states: Every asymptotic curve $c: I \rightarrow S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$  ( $II(c',c')=0$, where $II$ is the second fundamental form) with curvature $\kappa \neq 0$ and torsion $\tau$ satisfies the equation $\tau^2=-K$, where $\tau$ is the torsion of the curve and $K$ the Gauß-curvature of the surface $S$.

Proof: Let $c(s)$ be an aymptotic curve with $II(c',c')=0$. Then the normal curvature of $c$ vanishes. Hence, $e_2$ is tangential to the surface (so far is everything alright), but now it goes on with, then $e_3 = \nu$. 
I mean, I see that $e_3$ is then either $+ \nu$ or $- \nu$, but I don't see why the $+$ sign is already clear here.

Then it goes on like $\tau= \langle e_2',e_3 \rangle = \langle e_2', \nu \rangle $ which is just definition and the fact we just proved, but now it is claimed that this is equal to $II(e_1,e_2).$

Then the author claims that 
$K = Det(II)/Det(I) = II(e_1,e_1)II(e_2,e_2) - (II(e_1,e_2))^2 = 0 - \tau^2.$

Apparently, the determinant of the metric tensor is supposed to be equal to one here(why?).

You find this proof in this book:

It is theorem 3.19 on page 85: [see here](http://books.google.de/books?id=TyqUnlyV4Y4C&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=proof%20beltrami%20enneper&source=bl&ots=WZwV0mkT4h&sig=FitUfYe7wJ8ZCYcehLYa2Ucej7Q&hl=de&sa=X&ei=qN9xVKqzJoT8ywPO-4KoBg&ved=0CGcQ6AEwCDgK#v=onepage&q=proof%20beltrami%20enneper&f=false)

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Here's a part of the answer. $Det(I) = 1$ is true since $e_2$ is tangent, and so $e_1$ and $e_2$ are an orthonormal basis of the tangent plane. Thus
$$
Det(I) = I(e_1,e_1)I(e_2,e_2) - I(e_1,e_2)^2 = 1\cdot1-0^2 = 1,
$$
as claimed.

Comment: @jflipp but aren't the elements of the metric tensor, the basis vectors of the surface's tangent space? so: $Det(I) = (\partial_u f, \partial_u f) (\partial_v f,\partial_v f) - (\partial_u f , \partial_v f)^2$ rather than the unit vectors of the curve?

Comment: @jfilipp I mean by this logic, it would seem to be true that you would just need to pick an ONB of the tangent plane and then you could derive that the determinant of the metric tensor is always one.

Comment: This is indeed true. Note that the determinant of the metric tensor depends on the basis. You can always pick an ONB at a single point. It's more difficult to do this locally or along a curve. In the situation of your question, along the curve we have the orthonormal basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$ of the tangent plane. With regard to this basis, I has the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. The important point is that, when computing $K$ we have to use the _same_ basis for II. But we do this: $Det(II) = II(e_1,e_1)II(e_2,e_2) - II(e_1,e_2)^2.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $c \colon I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth enough curve with arclength parametrization and consider the associated Frenet-Serret frame. That is, $e_1(t) = c'(t)$, $e_2(t) = \frac{c''(t)}{||c''(t)||}$ and $e_3(t) = e_1(t) \times e_2(t)$. How does the frame change if we change the orientation of the curve? Define $\tilde{c}(t) = c(-t)$. Then $\tilde{e_1}(t) = \tilde{c}'(t) = -c'(-t) = -e_1(-t)$, $\tilde{e_2}(t) = e_2(-t)$ and $\tilde{e_3}(t) = \tilde{e_1}(t) \times \tilde{e_2}(t) = -e_3(-t)$. You can check that the curvature and the torsion of the curve are independent of its orientation, but the Frenet-Serret frame does depend on the orientation as $e_1$ and $e_3$ get flipped.

By the discussion above, reversing orientation if necessary, you can guarantee that $e_3$ in your case will be $\nu$ and not $-\nu$.

As to why $\tau = II(e_1,e_2)$, we have

$$ II_{c(t_0)}(e_1,e_2) = -\left< (d_{c(t_0)}\nu)(e_1), e_2(t_0) \right> = -\left< \left. \frac{d\nu(c(t))}{dt} \right|_{t=t_0}, e_2 \right> = -\left< e_3'(t_0), e_2(t_0) \right> = \left< e_2'(t_0), e_3(t_0) \right> = \tau(t_0) $$
where the equality
$$ -\left< e_3'(t_0), e_2(t_0) \right> = \left< e_2'(t_0), e_3(t_0) \right> $$
follows by differentiating
$$ \left< e_3(t), e_2(t) \right> \equiv 0. $$

Regarding your question about the determinant, note that a bilinear form $f \colon V \otimes V \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ doesn't have a well-defined notion of determinant as a number. If $A_B(f)$ is the matrix representing $f$ in a basis $B$, then $A_{B'} = S^T A_B S$ where $S$ is an invertible change of basis matrix. Thus, $\det(A_{B'})(f) = \det(S)^2 \det(A_B)(f)$ and so the determinant is well-defined (independent of basis) only up to a square of the field $\mathbb{F}$. For example, if $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$, then by choosing an appropriate basis, the determinant of the matrix representing the bilinear form can be made $0,1$ or $-1$. However, if you have two bilinear forms $f,g \colon V \otimes V \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ with $g$ nondegenerate then the ratio $\frac{\det(A_B(f))}{\det(A_B(g))}$ does not depend on the basis $B$ in which $f$ and $g$ are represented **simultaneously**. The statement that $K = \frac{\det(II)}{\det(I)}$ should be interpreted in this way. You can compute the ratio using a coordinate frame, but you can also compute the ratio using an orthonormal frame in which $\det(I) = 1$.

Comment: ah, so we assume that the curve is arc-length parametrized and we have this particular choice of orientation. well, alright, then I see it. thanks

Comment: if you could give me a hint, why the two determinants look the way they do, it would help me a lot. as I tried to indicate in the comment above, I don't see why the determinant can be represented by plugging $e_1,e_2$ into the form. the metric tensor and the second fundamental form are purely determined by the surface, so why can they be represented by the curve?

Comment: sorry apparently I forgot to ping you

Comment: I'll add an explanation in an hour or so, but the point is that a bilinear form doesn't have a well-defined notion of a determinant as a number, only the ratio makes sense, and you can compute it any way you want.

Comment: thank you very much, I appreciate your effort

Comment: okay, normally, when you perform a change of basis, you consider $A_{B'} = S^{-1} A_B S$ and in that case we would have $det(A_{B'}) = det(A)$, could you explain why we here transform differently?

Comment: sorry should have pinged you again.

Comment: Because you represent a bilinear form $f \colon V \otimes V \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ and not a linear map $L \colon V \rightarrow V$. You can read about it in any reference that discusses bilinear forms - for example, http://people.virginia.edu/~mah7cd/Math5651/Lecture15.pdf.